# Compute top view of different layers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to improvise solution to the problem, where we are given different layers and each layer has interleaved colors between discrete range and we have to compute the top view of these layers altogether.
Precisely its how different layers are projected into one.

For example,

[image]

And so far I have few insights,

```
We need to sort these segments based on ending points (so that I can
sweep linearly from 0 to 6)

Split these sorted items into unit intervals. eg. 0-1 (black), 0-1
(red), 1-2 (red), 2-3 (black), 2-3(green), 3-4 (green), 3-4 (red),
4-5 (red), 5-6 (black)

Push each interval into hashmap and update the color for hashmap for
given interval if it is in a upper layer.

eg. if we push 0-1 (red) (at layer 0) and we encounter 0-1 (black)
(at layer 2) we update map with key 0-1 to black. 

Print the map values.
```

Any ideas to improvise from step 2?

Comment: What do you mean by *improvise*? What is the exact input format?

Comment: Input format can be list of tuples says (start, end, height, color). By improvise I mean any other optimal solutions or improvements over current approach.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is just like [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/POSTERS/) problem on SPOJ, It can be solved efficiently by either a segment tree or a binary indexed tree, you can refer to [this](http://zobayer.blogspot.in/2011/01/spoj-posters.html) nice blog or go through [this](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18588) discussion

Comment: Hey I'm finding difficult to understand. 
So segment tree insertion takes an interval (l, r) and builds sub trees for all sub intervals of (l, r) and assigns the given color to all these nodes.
What do we do next?

Comment: So now for every node just check which colour paints that node in the top view